# Problem 6.25 in Fulton's Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The problem reads as follows:

> Show that $[x_1:\ldots:x_n]\mapsto[x_1:\ldots:x_n:0]$ gives an isomorphism of $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ with $H_\infty\subset\mathbb P^n$. If a variety $V$ in $\mathbb P^n$ is contained in $H_\infty,V$ is isomorphic to a variety in $\mathbb P^{n-1}$. Any projective variety is isomorphic to a closed sub variety $V\subset\mathbb P^n$ (for some $n$) such that $V$ is not contained in any hyperplane in $\mathbb P^n$.

This statement is very similar to Proposition I.4.9 of Hartshorne, which states that any variety of dimension $r$ is birational to a hypersurface of $\mathbb{P}^{r+1}$. However, Fulton has not yet talked at all about dimensions of varieties or birational maps.

I am not sure how to approach this problem. Also, my intuition is failing me in seeing why or how the statement of the problem can be true. Any hints?

Comment: Your parenthetical «i.e.» remark is not right, if the rest is to hold.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: You mean that the statement does not hold if $X$ is quasi-projective? I think i know where the problem is with my writing: Fulton actually says that $X$ should be isomorphic to a "closed subvariety".

Comment: You want to conclude that the variety is isomorphic to a projective variety satisfying certain conditions. It has to be projective to begin with!

Comment: Pick an X which is affine variety, say an affine line. That is not isomorphic to any closed subvariety of any projective space.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I am glad, because as i said in my question, i could not see why this is true. By the way, i edited the question providing the exact wording of Fulton. When Fulton says "projective variety" he means either closed projective or what Hartshorne calls quasi-projective: open inside a closed projective variety.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: In your example with the affine line, how do you see that it is not isomorphic to any closed subvariety of any projective space?

Comment: An affine line has nonconstant regular functions, and there are no nonconstant regular functions on a projective variety.

Comment: If his definition of projective variety includes nonclosed open subsets of closed algebraic sets in projective space, then the result is simply wrong.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Looks like you are right. I appreciate your teaching :) Maybe you can update your answer regarding that matter for future reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Consider a linear subspace of minimal dimension containing your variety.

Comment: In particular, this has nothing to do with the result you quote from Hartshorne, really.